# What does "has been taken in" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, idioms

> Mr. Johnson has been **taken in** for more than 20 years by this con artist.

Does this mean that this con artist has been duping Mr. Johnson for 20 years?

Comment: *yes*, exactly.

Comment: Most likely so, but of course it depends on context. If the con artist bilks people out of their investments, but has rented a room to Mr. Johnson for the past two decades, the sentence could mean something different. (This isn't likely, but it might be worth mentioning. A phrase like _take in_ doesn't always mean the same thing every time those two words are used together.)

Answer (score 1):

"Take in" is a Phrasal Verb that [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+in) *to deceive or swindle*.

So the sentence:

> Mr. Johnson has been taken in for more than 20 years by this con artist.

is similar in meaning to

> Mr. Johnson has been deceived for more than 20 years by this con artist.

Answer (score 0):

As a trivial aside, you get your pants or a dress "taken in", when you take them to the tailor, and have them made tighter at the waist.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. "Taken in" is an [idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) in this context.

Comment: I think this term comes from the fact that these kinds of cons were known as *confidence schemes* and those that practiced it were *confidence men* or *con* men.  These men would pretend to "*take you into* their confidence" by telling you information that was designed to make you want to hand over your money.  You were said to be *taken in* when you believed what they were telling you.  If you remained skeptical, then you were *not taken in* by the con.